# Is using RESTful Api as a custom web app backend needed?

Tags: php, ajax, rest

I am currently working on a web application which will use a lot of ajax for data retrieval. Certain parts of the data should only be accessible if a user is authenticated. I would down the road like to have an easy to use API for other applications but currently the only use of the API is driving the web application.

Is it worth it for me to implement a REST API vs a more customized traditional one?

I have looked into using rest and so far I have found the following

- User authentication would be more difficult due to the server not storing state
- The api would be unable to server multiple data items in the same request leading to a larger overhead
- Rest api would be magnitudes more extendable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've given the 3 best reasons I can think of that would go into answering your question.  It comes down to the answers that only you can give to those questions.

My approach has been to have a "mini" API in each of our clients sites for "their" stuff, and our "main" API that becomes a reposititory of common, or important functions that extend beyond "just theirs".  They're all built on the same foundation, so it's quite easy to switch and trade them around as necessary.

Also, by encoding the results as json, we're able to return many, many data items in a single call (whole tables of columns all at once if need be).  I'd recommend looking at [ReSTLER, by Luracast](http://luracast.com/products/restler/), if you want to see who they do it - it's a nice starting point.

**EDIT** showing *very* simnple multi-value return:

```
if(is_array($result)) {
    echo json_encode(array_values($result));
}else{
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Using Luracast ReSTLer, this code will return everything that PHPInfo contains in a single call:

```
    ob_start();
    phpinfo($module);
    $info_arr = array();
    $info_lines = explode("\n", strip_tags(ob_get_clean(), "<tr><td><h2>"));
    $cat = "General";
    foreach($info_lines as $line)
    {
        preg_match("~<h2>(.*)</h2>~", $line, $title) ? $cat = $title[1] : null;
        if(preg_match("~<tr><td[^>]+>([^<]*)</td><td[^>]+>([^<]*)</td></tr>~", $line, $val))
        {
            $info_arr[$cat][$val[1]] = $val[2];
        }
        elseif(preg_match("~<tr><td[^>]+>([^<]*)</td><td[^>]+>([^<]*)</td><td[^>]+>([^<]*)</td></tr>~", $line, $val))
        {
            $info_arr[$cat][$val[1]] = array("local" => $val[2], "master" => $val[3]);
        }
    }
    return Utilities::arrayToObject($info_arr);
```

Comment: How do you handle getting multiple data objects back in json? For example if I wanted to get back tasks `[1,2,3]` how could I transmit that command restfully? I was thinking I could only do site.com/tasks/1

Comment: Just added my code to the answer - We've got many, many servers, so I actually have a private API that in a single call, returns the full Apache/PHP/Mysql configuration - every conceivable variable that they use in a single call so that I can troubleshoot anything I'm dealing with.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much, this is the first lead I have had on this, looks like REST it is

Comment: Wow that is an incredibly easy framework, I already have a setup implemented. Thanks!

Comment: I know, I was real pleased to find it.  That was partially why we started using them in client specific sites (ease of use), then as particular functions "ripened" into something good for general use, it could easily be added to our general API.