# Restful API or Traditional web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, web-applications, backbone.js, restful-architecture

I see web application community seems to have two different way to build a rich experience web applications.

1. Build a backend as pure Restful API server, and use javascript MVC frameworks like backbone + UX design frameworks like twitter-bootstrap to build the UI frontend.

   -- I see people call this a think-client approach coz lots of logic happens on browser side; plus, designing Restful API interface (especially an extensible one) requires a lot of extra thinking process than the following approach
2. Use a web application framework like RoR or Django to build the web app, the widely used approach.

This question is sort of related to [Is using RESTful Api as a custom web app backend needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862839/is-using-restful-api-as-a-custom-web-app-backend-needed). I know that approach 1 may help reusing the development work for supporting native apps, but how much more up-front overhead it impose over approach 2?

Comment: It depends on many factors including: developer skills, platform capabilities, user requirements, devices, performance, interactions, etc. I'd even argue that either approach can take the same amount of time -- it just depends, and both have proven to be very practical and successful.

Answer (score 1):

The backend/frontend split is a simple example of creating services. The concept of services is very powerful especially as you start to scale to lots of users and add new features.

To answer your question, you do have to make an investment in implementing both an API and a front end as two separate applications. If you only ever plan to have a web client then a traditional rails/django app probably makes sense. On the other hand if you plan to have a variety of clients (mobile, web, cli) then an service/API based structure makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

A RESTful API, or some web services API is necessary if you use a thick-client especially when using a framework.

In approach 2, web services (e.g. RESTful API) are not needed, as you are serving static pages.  However, to do any AJAX on the pages, will require what are effectively web services, although they might not look particularly RESTful.